# Equivalence of curved space and Hamiltonian with potential

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, curvature, geodesic

Assume we have a vector space in which some equations of motion are governed by a Hamiltonian (kinetic + potential energy) as per $H(q,p)=T(p)+V(q)$, mostly with $T(p)=p^2/(2m)$.

In Physics, it is said that one can put the potential $V$ somehow in the curvature of the space.
So we are in the setting of a Riemannian manifold, say $M$, equipped with a "metric" (inner product in  $TM$, the tangent bundle) $g_x:T_xM\times T_xM\to\mathbb{R}$ defined at every $x\in M$.
Then one can define the geodesics...

- What is actually the notion of this equivalence roughly spoken "curvature without forces is equal to flat space with forces" ?
- What is the mathematicaly precise  way to "transform" the potential energy (the "forces") into the curvature defined by the Riemannian metric, which in Physics is normally given in coordinate reference system in matrix representation as $g_{ab}(x) \overset{?}{=} \text{some function of }V(x)$?

Edit: Is it somehow related to [Maupertuis's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27s_principle), or [Geodesics as Hamiltonian flows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_as_Hamiltonian_flows)?

Comment: Forces cannot, generally speaking, be encoded in a curvature of *space*, but they can (in some cases) be encoded in a curvature of space*time*. [This lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBlCu1zgD4Y&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_&index=9) gives a pretty good overview of the correspondence.

Comment: Can you explain this correspondence (what is it mathematically precisely, maybe in terms of geodesics on Riemannian Manifold), and which is more useful in some applications?